# Execute a bunch of command lines in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I want to start a program from VB.net and have control over it later(i want to show the window when i want, and minimize it after 5 seconds).

Now to start the program, it first needs to run a .bat file with a bunch of CALL- and SET- commands and it defines some variables and then the last command is the

```
START "Title App" /B ....
```

Now i am able to run this bat script with the process.start method from inside the vb.net app, but then i lose control over the started application (which gets started on top of my vb.net application).

My question is:

Is there a way to let vb.net run these commands (call ..., SET ...) from the batch file first, and then start the application with the process.start method?

Answer (score 0):

To control the last command in a batch, you'll need to emulate the shell yourself.

The `SET` commands need to be replaced with calls to `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`, or manipulation of `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`.

Then you can call `Process.Start` as wanted.